# Pass a click through a view

Tags: android, android-view

I have a screen overlay which is managed by a foreground service which displays a transparent view at the bottom corner of the screen. I have implemented my own RelativeLayout and GestureDetector to detect when a fling touch is made on the transparent view to show a detailed view.

All that works perfectly but the problem is, on the part of the screen where the view is put, clicks are lost in my overlay. Obviously the clicks should go through the view to whatever activity the user is currently interacting with.

I have tried making my root RelativeLayout not clickable as

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

But as expected it's not working.

Comment: This is not the proper way that you want to achieve. Search web for Chat Heads or Messenger Bubble

Comment: I have made the chat head like Messenger. But I have added another option that let's the users to just swipe from the bottom corner and voila. If the user doesn't want to be interrupted all the time with the chat head, they have to have the option

Comment: Your chat head must be inflated from a Service. Basically, you are intercepting touches if you are using a transparent activity, or having a view that inflated from a service matches with screen.

Comment: @EmreAktürk I have edited my question

Comment: You can try to override your onTouchEvents to return false in your overlay view which makes touches doesnt be consumed but i dont think its going to work since previous activity is not a parent of overlayed view. Another workaround could be stop the service since your preference activity started and start back when preferences are done.

Comment: @EmreAktürk That would work good but is there anyway that i can do this for other places other than my app?

Comment: I am sorry i don't have an idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will answer the question if I figure it out.